# mat-form-field is invisible

Tags: html, css, angular

I am very new in angular and I tried to write project that have two input field.
and I have a problem that I cant see those field on the website but they are clickable and I can write text in them. it happend to me after I added mat-error to those two field.
Someone know what is my problem.

this is my app.component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Yooz application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.component.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- website title -->
  <h1 class="title">
    Welcome to my Website
  </h1>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field class="emailFormField">
      <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="email" type="text" name="none">
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['email'].hasError('required')">
        It is required field
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field class="passwordFormField">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="password" type="text" name="none">
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['password'].hasError('required')">
        It is required field
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validator,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'yoozProject';
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DevTools console will probably tell you exactly what is wrong. Open your Angular app, press F12 and check out the console tab.

I think the issue is a mismatch in your form. In the HTML your referencing to 'email' and 'password' while in the formbuilder you're using 'name' and 'lastName'.